# Who can create a MAC? Who can verify a MAC?

Tags: mac

I have read many answers but I cannot get the basic explanation. There's no need for full details. I just need some basic information about who can create a mac and verify it.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who holds the key can create a MAC. For any secure MAC it should be *computationally infeasible to create* a MAC without knowledge of the key.

By the correctness of a MAC, *anyone who holds the key can verify* it. In pretty much any practical MAC, the key is also *needed* to verify, but this is not something that's actually implied by the functionality or security definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Given that a secret key was exchanged among some parties any of them can authenticate/verify a message using some MAC implementation in conjunction with the shared key. Typically you would share a key between 2 parties because otherwise you cannot tell who was the sender. However, this is not to be confused with the property of non-repudiation that you get from using a digital signature algorithm because in the case of a MAC, for a given message you cannot tell who generated the MAC (because both parties use the same shared key for the generation).